# Excel VBA: Making a Boolean Function to detect if any Cells in Range are a certain colour

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to create a function which will return a True or False value based on a range which contains a certain type of colour for any of those cells within that range. In this instance the colour is red (3). I'm trying to build the code so that if one of the cells within the range is red then the value returned will be True.

Does anybody know what is wrong with the code below?

```
Function CheckIfRed(Cells As Range) As Boolean

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim counter As Long

For Each currentCell In Cells
    If currentCell.Interior.Color = 3 Then
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next currentCell

If counter > 0 Then
    CheckIfRed = True
End If

End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What happens? Have you stepped through the function using the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using `.Color` but testing against the color *index*. Use `.ColorIndex` instead. You are also doing too much work:

```
Function CheckIfRed(Cells As Range) As Boolean
    Dim currentCell As Range

    For Each currentCell In Cells
        If currentCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            CheckIfRed = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next currentCell
End Function
```

This code terminates as soon as it finds a single red cell. It also exploits the fact that Booleans have a default value of False which is automatically returned if the loop completes without finding a red.

Be aware that checking the color index is not always sufficient if e.g. the color has been set by conditional formatting.

Comment: Thanks very much, I did think that adding a counter in might have been a bit too much, I had resorted to adding in in because my first few attempts weren't giving me the result I was hoping for